# Разделение запросов api и frontend apache2

Tags: laravel, apache, apache2

Всем привет! У меня есть 2 репозитория на гитхабе: frontend (SPA на vue) + backend (laravel). В репозитории с api есть routes/api.php, где лежат все API-endpoint'ы, а также web.php, где все запросы перенаправляются на SPA, т.е. таким образом:

```
Route::get('{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

`SpaController@index` возвращает рендеринг view SPA

Сейчас мой деплой на сервер происходит следующими шагами:

1. npm run production
2. копирую скомпилированный css+js в папку `public/` laravel
3. копирую скомпилированный html в шаблон `spa.blade.php`
4. `git push` на клиенте и `git pull` на сервере

**Проблема:** чтобы выложить новую версию frontend'а, мне приходится делать дополнительный коммит в мастер репозитория backend'a. Пока я работаю с этим проектом один, такой костыльный воркфлоу жизнеспособен. Но скоро мне нужно будет сюда подключать еще одного фронтендера и я хочу полностью распараллелить эти репозитории.

**Вопрос:** каким образом это можно сделать? На данный момент, я вижу только 1 способ - это редирект на уровне apache роутов `/api` на бэкенд, а остальные вести на папку фронта. Но как это сделать правильно?

Мои текущие настройки apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/chain.pem

    <Directory /var/www/domain.com/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: А почему вы их делите через апачь? Запросы автоматически делятся в зависимости от присутствия хедера `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @n.osennij проблема именно в разделении корневых репозиториев проекта. Я хочу их разделить, что фронт шел в отдельном репозитории на сервере. Пока что получается, что чтобы выкатить новую версию фронта, мне нужно делать новый коммит-пуш-пул на мастере бэкэнда (с новой версией css+js), что не есть хорошо